# Wrong letter with \textsc

Tags: uppercase

I am using `babel-azerbaijani` package and there are rules for upper-case and lowercase. However, in my document it does not work properly.

```
\textsc{Alqoritmlərin Sirri}
```

Will produce:

[image]

Expected text should be(İ with dot on top):

ALQORİTMLƏRİN SİRRİ

Suppose babel package has a bug, is there any workaround to apply custom uppercase rule?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes it is xelatex.

Comment: @egreg actually it is the same problem. But workaround solution from there produces weird result. The dot is not in the center, it is on the top right of the letter.

Comment: The accent positioning will depend on the font and which tex engine you are using, please add a small complete document to your question, if there is a new specific issue we can reverse the voting to close as duplicate and add an answer here.

Comment: the accent being top right is usually a sign of a font issue with a Unicode combining accent character not combining so appearing just after the base character rather than being used as a marker to make theglyph with the accented base character

Comment: If I use a font with dotted I, and small caps feature, and correct `babel` setting, it works OK: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[azerbaijani]{babel}\babelfont{rm}{Linux Biolinum G}\begin{document}S\symbol{"0130}RR\symbol{"0130}\textsc{Alqoritmlərin Sirri}
\symbol{"0130}i I\symbol{"0131} \end{document}`